# R ggplot2 changing units of an axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Couldn't find this in a google search, so I thought I'd document it here.

My problem was I needed to change my y-axis labels to basis points, as opposed to standard units, but I couldn't find a way to fix this simple problem, I had my plot like this:

```
p <- ggplot(plotdat, aes(x = name, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
      geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

but I kept trying to use this line but I kept getting an error.

```
p + scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) as.character(x*10000), breaks = 10)
Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

How can I change the format of my y axis tick labels?

Answer (score 4):

To format the axis tick labels, use the `formatter` option in `scale_continuous`. So:

```
p = p + scale_y_continuous(formatter = function(x) format(x*10000))
```

This should give you basis points.

Comment: Your answer (and question) might be more helpful with an example using a minimal and reproducible dataset.

Comment: `scale_*` doesn’t seem to have a `formatter` argument in the current version of ggplot, and this code results in an error. Changing it to `labels = function…` works.

Answer (score 2):

The [most voted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11974525/6873133) is a bit outdated and the `formatter` option doesn't exist anymore. It seems to be updated to `labels` instead. Below is a minimal example demonstration a before and after.

```r
# Load libraries
library(dplyr)   # CRAN v1.0.6
library(ggplot2) # CRAN v3.3.5
library(scales)  # CRAN v1.1.1

# Without transformation
iris %>%
    ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

```r
# With transformation
iris %>%
    ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_comma(scale = 1000))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>